# GRE over IPSec behind FW

Tags: linux, routing, nat, ipsec, gre

I have a checkpoint S-Box which is a gateway for network 192.168.0.0/24.
Internal IP is 192.168.0.1.

On the S-Box configured static VPN tunnel with local IP 10.x.x.x and remote 10.y.y.y.
I need to create a GRE tunnel with local 10.z.z.z and remote 10.w.w.w;

The problem that S-Box doesn't support GRE tunneling. (but recognized it and may forward)
May I create a tunnel from linux machine (debian, kernel 2.6.26) placed at 192.168.0.5?
How I do it?

Also, the other side want my addresses be 10.q.q.q/24, how do i provide this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How to setup a GRE tunnel is described at http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.tunnel.gre.html
With iptables you should be able to rewrite packets. Something along the lines of:

iptables -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT -t nat -o gre0 -d 10.y.y.y --to-source 10.q.q.1-10.q.q.254